# VARCHAR(254) vs. VARCHAR(255)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043556/mysql-why-varchar254-and-not-varchar255) about the different between VARCHAR(254) and VARCHAR(255) in MySQL.

Is there something similar in HiveQL that must be taken into account? Maybe HiveQL implements some storage engine similar to that of MySQL and this should be kept in mind when designing tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive does not have cliffs on column lengths like those in mysql. Instead the considerations are about compression and columnar vs row storage. Here is a reference talking about some of these compression and storage options.

http://www.adaltas.com/blog/2012/03/13/hdfs-hive-storage-format-compression/

You can consider Text, Sequence, RC/ORC Columnar formats. Then there are the compression options .  None of these are focused on the column lengths in the same way as mysql.